# Why does a call to Model.create!() return when the mysql transaction hasn't completed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I watched a video where their signup page was causing issues because the call to:

```
person = Person.create!(params)
```

returns when in fact mysql hasn't necessarily completed the transaction yet.

Why would it return before the transaction?

video: http://cdn.confreaks.com/system/assets/datas/5097/original/1119-gogaruco2012-services-scale-backgrounding-and-wtf-is-going-on-here-small.mp4?1349207263

Comment: So is it `.find()` or `.create!()` call?

Comment: create! sorry, i'll fix that.

Comment: That video is 30 minutes long... please add when in the video David talks about this

Answer (score 0):

i did not watch the video, but from what i know about transactions, calling `create` or `find` or whatever, is not within any transaction!

you need to define transactions in the code yourself:

```
Person.transaction do
   [...]
end
```

here are some nice examples of how to work with transactions in rails: http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/